# cannot update GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Before installing windows 10 i had 2 partition on my disk one windows 10 and ubuntu 21.10 my problem was that i could not update windows..so i downloaded the iso and re-install it..everything good windows is up and running but..
After installing windows 10 i tried to fix grub using the bootrepair cd tool (from usb) but after a while showed me this message "**grub-pc cancelled**" so i then gathered information about it from the bootrepair and paste it here **https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/68YZns9nvG/** can you please me help me as im not experienced. And in this drive i have everything!

Thank you in advance George.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 tells you it was the 2021-October release given the *year.month* format used for Ubuntu's main products (2000 is added to the *year*).  It's EOL can be calculated by adding 9 months to Oct.2021, so even without reading any release announcements/notices it's easy to calculate. The first release on an *even* year is *long-term-support* or LTS.  Ubuntu 21.10 was the third of the non-LTS releases in the two year *development* cycle that results in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; the *release-upgrade* being to the next release in that cycle.

Comment: My main reason posting this it is to move to 22.04 LTS but when I'm trying to do this from usb boot it tells me that it will delete all my data.. And thus i can't log in to it i ask if there is any know how on how to do it either by usb update or by logging in again and do an upgrade.. But since i don't have access to the grub anymore i can't do it by upgrade.

Comment: I found a way to do it.. By installing "Linuxreader" in Windows and with it i backed up all my data from Ubuntu partition to two other disks i had spare.. And now I'm gonna do a clean install of 22.04 by USB.. but I'd like to know if this happens again.. How i can upgrade to a new version via USB without losing my files?

Comment: But please remove linux reader from windows.